# Get axios using promise and output in html with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to get the json output and print some HTML in the same page. How do  I get expressjs to work with axios and promise? I'm quite a newbie with nodejs/expressjs. Thank you for your advice.

````
var express = require('express'),
    axios = require('axios');

var app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('Requested ');
    axios.get('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees')
        .then(data => res.send(data))
        .catch(err => res.send(err))
});


app.listen(app.get('port'), ()=> console.info('Application listening on port ' + app.get('port') ));```
````

Comment: What is the issue you are running into? Any errors? What happens when you navigate to `localhost:3000`?

Answer (score 0):

**Check the below code**

```
var express = require("express"),
  axios = require("axios");

var app = express();

app.set("port", 3000);

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log("Requested ");
  axiosTest().then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
});

function axiosTest() {
  return axios
    .get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
    .then(response => {
      return response.data;
    });
}
app.listen(app.get("port"), () =>
  console.info("Application listening on port " + app.get("port"))
);
```

Comment: Thanks Chandan. That was very helpful in understanding this. 
How do you convert that into "async/await" format instead of promise?

Comment: for asyn & await refer [Sample](https://gist.github.com/wesbos/1866f918824936ffb73d8fd0b02879b4)

Comment: Axios requests are promises only. You can simply use **const res = await axios.get(URI);** and wrap that into an **async** function with try/catch.